# Página de perfil - PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Olá !

Estou tentando criar uma página para cada usuário que se registre no site, porém não estou conseguindo, basicamente o perfil funciona da seguinte forma: cada perfil é linkado pelo userID, que pode ser acessado ao mudar a url, por exemplo: "profile.php?userid=1", caso o usuário coloque um userid que não existe no banco de dados irá aparecer uma mensagem de erro.
Sem o uso de declarações preparadas tem funcionado corretamente, porém quando tentei utilizar as declarações preparadas para aumentar a segurança apenas recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   object given in C:\wamp64\www\MinhaLista\includes\profile.inc.php on
>   line 17

Conexão com o banco de dados:

```php
<?php
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_username = "root";
$db_password = "";
$db_name = "users_registered";

$conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);

if(!$conn) {
    die("A conexão com o banco de dados falhou: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

Código do perfil com declarações preparadas (que apresenta erro):

```php
<?php
    include "db.inc.php";

    if (!isset($_GET['userid'])) {
        echo "Erro ao encontrar o userid";
    }
    else {
        $userid = $_GET['userid'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userID=?";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
            echo "Erro ao preparar as declarações";
        }
        else {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $userid);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            $result = mysqli_num_rows($stmt);
            if ($result < 0) {
                echo "Esse usuário não existe";
            }
            else if ($result > 0) {
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    $username = $row['userName'];
                    $userimage = $row['userImage'];
                }
            }
            else {
                echo "Esse usuário não existe.";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Sem as declarações preparadas (que funciona)

```php
<?php
 include "db.inc.php";

    if (!isset($_GET['userid'])) {
        echo "Erro ao encontrar o userid";
    }
    else {
        $userid = $_GET['userid'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userID=$userid";
        $result = mysqli_query ($conn, $sql);
        $queryresults = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            if ($queryresults < 0) {
                echo "Usúario não encontrado";
            }
            else if ($queryresults > 0) {
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    $username = $row['userName'];
                    $userimage = $row['userImage'];
                }
            }
            else {
                echo "Usúario não encontrado";
            }
}
?>
```

Agradeço se alguém puder ajudar, não faço ideia de onde estou errando. Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na declaração:

```
$result = mysqli_num_rows($stmt);
```

O parâmetro `$stmt` é do tipo [`MySQLi_STMT`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.mysqli-stmt.php) que representa um comando preparado e
[`mysqli_num_rows()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) está esperando por um parâmetro do tipo [`MySQLi_Result`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.mysqli-result.php) que representa o conjunto de resultados da consulta feita ao banco de dados retornado por [`mysqli_stmt_get_result()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php). Por isso o erro.

Corrigindo e simplificando seu código:

```
<?php
    include "db.inc.php";

    if (isset($_GET['userid'])) {
        $userid = $_GET['userid'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userID=?";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        if(mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $userid);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            // Obtenha o conjunto de resultados da consulta
            $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
            // Passe o conjunto de resultados para mysqli_num_rows()
            $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            // A comparação é feita com o número de linhas obtidos
            if ($num_rows > 0) { 
                // Obtem uma linha do conjunto de resultados
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    $username = $row['userName'];
                    $userimage = $row['userImage'];
            } else {
                echo "Esse usuário não existe.";
            }     
        } else {
            echo "Erro ao preparar as declarações";
        }    
    } else {
        echo "Erro ao encontrar o userid";
    }
?>
```